# barcode app in windows mobile device

Tags: windows, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, barcode

I am going to write a barcode app for windows mobile device. I would like to know that is there any framework available for data manipulation so that I can query and update in the device and can synch the same data in the database servers like mssql,postgres and mysql.
I found [SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) in search but it seems that it can synch the data only with MSSQL. I need exactly like SQL-CE but it should work for other database servers also.